# Export entire folder using SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, export

I have a folder that contains many html, js, css and image files. I want to export the folder as a zip or in any possible way as long as it's in a bulk. Right now, the only option that I know of is to extract the files one by one using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the Library using the "Open with explorer" option, from here you can copy the everything or Folder and move it where you want.

[Copy or move library files by using Open with Explorer](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-Open-with-Explorer-aaee7bfb-e2a1-42ee-8fc0-bcc0754f04d2?CorrelationId=1ddb692d-b0f7-4093-9955-38c0549771d2&ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN)

Comment: This does not work for all systems, as file access can be prohibited in the explorer.

Comment: Hmm! Still works in Online, great! Year ago it was unaccessible (there was OneDrive instead)